# How can I alias a variable in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

I have a Grafana dashboard that displays Prometheus metrics for two AWS instances. I have a dashboard variable defined that returns the instance IDs I am interested in. For an "All" option I am using `".*"`. I match the resulting instance ID in my panel queries with `query{instance_id=~"$instance_id"}`.The query involved in defining that variable is similar to this:

```
label_values(is_foo, instance_id)
```

That query works and gives me a nice way to select instances from a drop down menu on the dashboard.

Now, one instance returns 1 for `is_foo` and the other returns 0. What I am trying to achieve is a way to refer to the instances with names `foo` (for when `is_foo` is 1) and `bar`. Preferably there would be a drop down menu with names `foo` and `bar` and an "All" option, similar to what exists now. In the legends I would like the names to appear as well. Basically I am looking for a way to alias the instance IDs with pretty naming.

I have tried defining custom variables, for example `foo_id` with `query_result(is_foo==1)` and then assigning these to a custom map variable, `foo : ${foo_id}` but the `foo_id` variable will not expand. Is such a thing possible? Can custom variables be chained together?